# Libraries stopped working after Xcode updated. React Native 0.62.2

Tags: ios, reactjs, macos, react-native

I had trouble when updating Mac data. After I updated to a certain Mac Version, Spotlight stopped working when using the emulator. That was solved after some time. However, after I updated XCode, some libraries in my app that worked previously stopped working, even images, as it shows in the picture below.
[image: Error Description]
(There should be a calendar component [like this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-658244428), also there are styles problems.)

I have searched for some ways to solve this trouble. I have tried this method as shown in this [reply](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-658244428). This solved the image not being shown problem, however, the other libraries are having the same trouble, and I don't how to solve them. I don't know what I could post here besides the package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^8.0.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^7.2.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^7.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^7.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.0",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "jsc-android": "^241213.1.0",
    "luxon": "^1.24.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.0.12",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.9.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.0.1",
    "eslint": "7.0.0",
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Is there a way to get the libraries to work? I really appreciate the time! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to clean install and make the project as clean as possible. However, after I uninstalled Xcode from the iOS Store, and installed directly from their [website](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), the code went back normal again. I am using version 11.7, and Xcode was the reason why my code did not work. What a mess.

I appreciate the help of the people around here! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to re install the node modules and run pod install inside ios directory.

1. Delete node_modules/ folder
2. run yarn install or npm install in root directory.
3. run pod install inside ios directory.

If still issue is not resolved the you can try clearing your derived data on
Xcode.

Go to Xcode => Preferences => Locations & click on arrow in front of /Xcode/DerivedData and then delete the derived data folder and restart your xcode.

Comment: This did not solve the problem. I have deleted the 'node_modules' folder, 'npm install', and 'pod installs' right after. I did clean the derived data but it still did not work. In addition, I have tried to clean using 'xcodebuild clean', cleaned the iOS build, reset the iOS simulator, cleaned metro-bundler-cache, react-native-packager-cache, and cleaned npm cache. This actually happened after the Mac updated and Xcode as well and I do believe it has to do something with them.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your node_modules, and before doing a clean install, remove ALL the carets from the package.json. That will install those exact versions. What you have now, might trigger the install of a newer version of a dependency that "should" not break anything, but I found that most of the time, this is what breaks my build.

So every "dependency: ^1.2.3" becomes "dependency: 1.2.3"

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I have tried doing the clean install from both the project and Xcode itself before, but I did not try to install the exact versions. That is interesting. I have changed them all, but it still did not work. I think it's mostly related to Xcode itself. Thanks for the time!

Comment: Did you also deleted your pods folder and do pod install again after installing the exact versions?

Comment: I deleted the pods folder, cleaned the ios project, and react project right after. It happened to have the same error.